# IIS 7+ Application Request routing balance between two different sites on the same box

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

I am looking to setup request routing on a single server.

- 1 incoming hostname (www.mysite.com)
- 2 websites (www1.mysite.com and www2.mysite.com)
- load spread evenly between them.

This is purely so that I can setup a Continuous Delivery solution, so that the site can be upgraded without any downtime, similar to a server farm, but without the extra servers.

Has anyone done this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i find to solve this problem is to create a webfarm and add itselft but with the port 8080.

So the incoming request will came on the port 80 and on the routing rule create a condition that validate the request with the incomming port 80.